# Tag issues I have found

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I have come across a few problems related to tags that I have outlined below:

1. I have not yet earned the privilege of creating tag synonyms, but have come across a few tags that *may* benefit from having a synonym relationship established.  This *may* also save some work and headache later if we establish them now.

   *synonym -> master*

   [web-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-app) -> [web-application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application)
   [webapp](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp) -> [web-application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application)
   [map](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) -> [maps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps)
   [internet-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-browser) -> [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser)
   [cloudstorage](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudstorage) -> [cloud](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud)
   [online-storage](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) -> [cloud](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud)
   [autocompletion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocompletion) -> [autocomplete](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete)
2. Misspelled tags - in some of these cases it appears that it could be a variation of spelling English words in different parts of the world. As such, the following is just my suggestion to avoid tags that are duplicate in nature, but should still be one tag.

   *synonym -> master*

   [customisation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customisation) -> customization (does not yet exist)
   [data-visualisation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualisation) -> [data-visualization](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization)
   [appstore](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appstore) -> app-store

Again, these are just my suggestions, I welcome any advice on this subject matter and want to open the discussion to improving the use of these tags, and any others that may need some refining.  Cheers.

Comment: As a tip, you can use `[tag:tag-name]` and it will be rendered in markdown with a link. To add to your list, I think [tag:appstore] should be renamed to [tag:app-store]

Comment: No-one have required 1250 reputation yet, so only moderators can create those. But your point stands.

Comment: @JohnB I think I fixed that.

Comment: Again, it would be cool if a Community Manager could take care of these :)

Comment: @JohnB Thank you for the tip.  I didn't use that feature because I've seen it happen on other SE sites that when you use that feature, the tag is auto added to the tags list.  And since only 5 tags are allowed in the tag list, I didn't want it being overrun with the tags we were going to be discussing; however, I will certainly keep it in mind in the future.  Cheers.

Comment: @SlyRaskal You've seen it auto create the tag? It's never done that to me.

Comment: @Seth: I just tried it again and it didn't do it.  Perhaps when I added a tag in the past, the preview area was so close to the tag list that I mistakenly thought it had added it to the tag list when it actually hadn't. But I was so certain that it had added a tag automatically for me.  Maybe I should reduce the amount of time I spend on the computer when it is late at night. ;) Cheers.

Comment: @JohnB, I have added your recommendation to correct the appstore tag to be app-store to my post.  Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I *did* rename [appstore](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appstore) to [app-store](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app-store). Sounds reasonable.

I also renamed some of these pluralization/hyphenation tags as they seemed appropriate. The unused tags left behind will be cleaned up shortly, and it will be more difficult to re-create them once the reputation limits are raised when the site goes public.

But tag synonyms are really designed to cover cases where two completely different words mean exactly the same thing. It wasn't really designed to cover variations in pluralization and hyphenation. Text completion should take care of that. When you type in a-u-t-o, the system is going suggest [autocompletion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocompletion) automatically. A good wiki excerpt should describe when that tags should be used.

I didn't see many instances of dueling tags beyond that. Let's see if any further problems arise in actual practice.

Comment: Thanks for addressing some of the culprits. My desire to change [tag:autocompletion] to 'autocomplete' was more of a semantic issue than anything else, not necessarily that it is misspelled. I see no issue in waiting to see how the other tags play out. Cheers.

Comment: I'm marking this accepted, but hoping that I remember to check back in the future regarding the remaining tags that we can revisit to see how things play out.  Thank again for your help.  Cheers.