# Tags for software that runs on a (web?) server

Tags: discussion, tags

I think it’s important to differentiate between two cases:

- looking for software **to install** on a server (= **self-hosted**)
- looking for software **installed** on a server (= **hosted**)

Ideally, this difference should be represented in the tags.

(If I understand it correctly, this was also [suggested by Gilles](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/406/60) in [Mysterious [cloud] tag](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/397/60).)

Why?

- **Not the same area of expertise.**
- **Browsing by tag should be helpful.** If someone is looking for answers recommending self-hosted solutions, having to dig through answers about hosted services is no fun, and vice versa.
- The **current use** shows that users often don’t specify in the question if they want/allow a hosted or a self-hosted solution.

That said …

#### Which tags to use?

- Currently, [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) is used most of the time, and for both cases.
- There is also [cloud-service](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-service) whose description (if I understand it correctly) implies that it’s only for hosted solutions. But why *cloud* vs. *web*?
- The description of [web-services](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-services) seems to imply that it’s about the concept described in the [Wikipedia article of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), but some questions seem to use it as a synonym to [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps)/[cloud-service](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-service).
- (**update 2015-10**) The tag [saas](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saas) (no description) is used on a few questions, too.
- Also to keep in the back of the head:

  - [web-apis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apis) (is this only about hosted APIs, or can it also apply to self-hosted?)
  - [cloud-storage](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage) (is this a particular kind of cloud service, or is it about the technical meaning, i.e., software to enable cloud storage?)

I don’t have strong feelings about *which* tags to use, as long as we *do* use two different tags.

Answer (score 4):

It *might* work to use the tags [self-hosted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-hosted) and [hosted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosted).

Advantages:

- By not including "web" in the tag name, we don’t restrict this tag to *web* applications, so we can use it for all kind of software that runs on servers (be it typical web applications used locally or in the intranet, or servers/tools that don’t have an HTTP interface).
- By not including "cloud" in the tag name, we get round the ambiguity of this term (technical definition with [characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Characteristics) vs. "everything in the Internet").

Disadvantages:

- As we can’t add [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) as synonym (because it would apply to both, [hosted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosted) and [self-hosted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-hosted)) and the new tags don’t have "web" in their name, tag discovery is harder for authors searching for "web" when adding tags.

  But for making tag discovery for question authors easier, maybe we could introduce "fake" synonyms like [hosted-web-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosted-web-app) and [self-hosted-web-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-hosted-web-app)?
- There would be no tag anymore for authors that accept both, hosted and self-hosted solutions (using both tags is only appropriate if *both* are required, which would apply only to rare cases).

What to do?

- [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps), [cloud-service](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-service), and [saas](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saas) retire.
- [cloud-storage](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage) should be used only for solutions enabling/managing/etc. [cloud storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_storage); if needed (in which case there might be a better name, to avoid confusion).
- [web-services](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-services) should be renamed (to avoid confusion) and used in the [W3C/programming sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service); if needed.
- [web-apis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apis): Decide if it’s restricted to the web; if not, retire and use [api](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) (e.g., in combination with [hosted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosted)).

Comment: It seems that the tag [tag:self-hosted] got created (used on 2 questions currently).

Comment: As it got no negative feedback, I [created](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17197/60) the [tag:hosted] tag.